# Find the Recurrence Relation For number of edges of a Bipartite Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I guess I am a bit confused about how recurrence relations work.

For a graph of $K(m,n)$, let's say $m = 3$. The number of edges would be $3n$. 
And for a graph of $K(n, n)$ the number of edges would be $n^2$.

But I don't know the *process* of how to interpret these into recurrence relations? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $m$. Let $e_n$ denote the number of edges in the graph $K_{m,n}$. Fix a vertex $v$ in the '$n$' sized partite set. Then every edge counted in $e_n$ is of two types: either it involves $v$, or it doesn't (these cases are disjoint). The former count is $e_1$ and the latter is $e_{n-1}$. So, we have $e_n=e_1+e_{n-1}$. Clearly, $e_1=m$ and so we have

> $e_n=m+e_{n-1}$. We also have the initial condition $e_1=m$.

Let us prove that $e_n=mn$ by induction on $n$. For $n=1$ this is obvious. Assume the result for $n-1$. Now, $e_n=m+e_{n-1}=m+(n-1)m$ by the induction hypothesis. Hence $e_n=mn$ and we are done.